# Can we depend on Django not verifying field length?

Tags: django

The `username` in `django.contrib.auth.User` allows upto 30 characters. Emails may exceed that, so I did an `alter` on the that column to extend it.

Django **delegates size checking** to the underlying database; so with Django+SQLite, there is nothing to verify the length of the data and Postgres throws an (IIRC) OperationError about too big data.

The scenario I fear: A future version of Django is going to check `user.save()` by **itself**; breaking functionality if I upgrade. Is Django's current behavior stable and documented?

Comment: It would probably be better to [customize Django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) to use email addresses (which can be properly validated using an `EmailField` and are not subject to the 30-character limit) than to use `username` and do the validation yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) that model validation is not called automatically:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.